# selectize.js on iOS requires double-tap to close an item in both safari and chrome

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

When the website is viewed on an iOS device I have to click on the close(x) button twice to deselect an item (country in country list) in dropdown menu created using `selectize.js`. It works fine on android and web.

Answer (score 0):

Well this was asked quite a while ago but I think I might have a solution.  I found this website explaining some stuff but wasn't happy with it's own solution.

[Double Tap Issue](https://css-tricks.com/annoying-mobile-double-tap-link-issue/)

So I created my own solution which works pretty good so far for me.

https://gist.github.com/PocketNinjaDesign/689e16e412a88dfd36dd08b26bebcacf

```
a.close {
  background: #fc0;

  @media (hover: hover) {
    &:hover {
      background: #f00;
    }
  }
}
```

All thanks to Mozilla ;-)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover